# Switch - Case Condition in Apache Trinidad

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

since I cannot find anything regarding switch - case condition in Apache Trinidad, I have to ask here.

I have a table with 9 columns and if column Message is not empty and column Commodity and Equity, only Commodity and Equity should be coloured red.

[image]

I thought about solving this problem with an switch - case condition but I think there is not any in Apache Trinidad.
Am I wrong and if yes, is there a possibility to solve this problem?

What I have is this thing:

```
<tr:column headerText="Equity"
    inlineStyle="#{(emirfacade.Error_Code_Reason ne null) and (emirfacade.Commodity ne null or emirfacade.Credit ne null or emirfacade.Equity ne null or emirfacade.ForeignExchange ne null or emirfacade.InterestRate ne null) ? 'background-color:red' : ''}">
<tr:outputText value="#{emirfacade.Equity}">
</tr:outputText>
</tr:column>
```

But what I want to have is that only the fields that are not empty in Commodity/Credit/etc. should be coloured red.
If they are empty then it does not matter, they should not be coloured red.

I am not so used to Apache Trinidad.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Use like #{emirfacade.message ne null  and emirfacade.commodity ne null and emirfacade.Equity ne null ?'background-color:red' :''}  on commodity  and Equity  column

Comment: The problem is dependent on which column is not empty this field should be coloured red. In the picture the third line InterestRate is not empty, so only this field should be coloured red, all the other ones should not. If I do it with a if condition, I would have done it like: if (Message ne null and InterestRate ne null) colour-red InterestRate else if (Message ne null and ForeignExchange  and InterestRate and x and y ) then colour-red ForeignExchange and all the other ones) but when 4 fields are not empty then the if statement would become even longer ... I hope I explained it better now.

Comment: So in 1st column all other column should be red except Credit?

Comment: No, not exactly. If column Message is not empty then check column Commodity whether it is empty, if yes then mark Commodity as red but at the same time Credit could also be filled with a number, therefore, mark this column red too. So, dependent on the Message column check whether all other columns are filled and if yes then mark them red but not all columns on the right side need to be filled.

Comment: What I think now would happen is that if I check Message ne null then if Commodity ne null then colour-red Commodity end if Equity ne null then colour-red Equity end if ... and so on, so I have to check every column whether it is filled or not and this would become very ugly and long code. I only want to have the columns coloured red that are not empty meaning the columns that have an integer in it ( Commodity, Equity, Credit, ForeignExchange, Interest can have integers but not all of them are always filled )

Comment: I think I solved it. I mixed it up by myself. There is nothing wrong with an if else statement on every column and then setting this column as red. Thanks for your help. Man should not code when he is tired :)